# Unhide ASP Textbox control in Javascript Function

Tags: .net, javascript, asp.net

I have the following control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" Width="95px" MaxLength="6" />
```

which i would like to be hidden/invisible on page load, and have the textbox appear after clicking a button/running some javascript without reloading the page.

Here's my current button:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdShowBox" runat="server" Text="Show Button" onclick="showBox(); return false"  />
```

and lastly here's my current javascript function:

```
                function showBox() {
                var theControl = document.getElementById("<%= textbox1.ClientID %>");
                theControl.style.display = "none";


                }
```

I was starting with just showing the box on load, then trying to click a button to make it hide, but I can't even get that to work :(  When I run the code as it is above I get a server error which says

Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'textbox1' is not declared.

Thanks for any help/advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the server-side visible property to false, this doesn't render the control at all on the client.  That's also why you can get the textbox1 error message.  Instead do:

```
<asp:TextBox id="textbox1" ... style="display:none" />
```

And then this element is rendered, but hidden.  Then this should work.

```
function showBox() {
    var theControl = document.getElementById("<%= textbox1.ClientID %>");
    theControl.style.display = "";
}
```

To show it.

Comment: It's a compiler error though, the getElementById is not returning null... are you sure this is the problem?

Comment: @Brian there is no `style` property on a `TextBox`. He'd have to associate a css class.

Comment: I got a compile error when trying the problem too, but it was a different one.  I would accept Vinay's answer though as going with OnClientClick seems to be the answer to this problem.

Comment: "@Brian there is no style property on a TextBox. He'd have to associate a css class."  

That's the main problem I was running into when trying to make this work..

Comment: ok so i was able to apply a style="display:none" tag to the textbox, which worked.  And then my only issue (which i didn't include in my orig post) was the textbox1.ClientID reference wasn't working because the control was in a formview control.  So I referenced it like: var theControl = document.getElementById("formview1$textbox1"); and theControl.style.display = "inline"; which worked!! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Controls that have properties defined that don't match a server-side property automatically push these down to the client side HTML element.  So style isn't a server-side property, it just renders it directly as is.  Glad to see it worked.  Yes formview and some other containers (where templates are involved) can cause additional headaches.

Answer (score 4):

onclick on a button is bound to a server side method.
use a normal html button or Use OnClientClick on the asp:button. also setting visible false on the textbox on the server will not even rencer the control in the first place trying hiding it by setting a css with display none.

Comment: i actually was using the OnClientClick, that was just a mistype when I was preparing this question.  thanks for your post.